# Periodic spikes in CPU usage, possibly queue related?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, supervisord, beanstalkd, laravel-5.3

I added a beanstalk queue to my application (running through [supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#supervisor-configuration)).

I noticed that my CPU usage was periodically spiking:

[http://i.imgur.com/0Fg1FQl.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4rno.png)

As far as I know, there's nothing in the queue. I've restarted beanstalkd multiple times. I noticed that when I stop all the supervisor processes, the CPU usage goes to basically zero.

**Is this normal behavior for queues even though there's nothing in the queue?** Is there any way to make the spikes less severe?

And if it helps, here's my supervisor worker configuration:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/laravel/artisan queue:work beanstalkd --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
```

Thanks.

Comment: what's the server spec?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it takes effort to load the relevant PHP files, and check the queue for new items, regardless of any work that is in the queue, which would be done.

Enabling Opcache to be used for command-line scripts, as well as faster versions of PHP, like v7, will help, as well as longer sleeps between runs to pause if there are no jobs in the queue.